# Issues with my Ruby Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems viewing the homepage in my rails application. When I run it I get the following error:

could not find gem 'rails  =3.1.0 x86-ming32 in any of the gem sources listed in the gemfile

The contents of my gem file is as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'

end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run it

May I ask how you are running it?

Instead of assuming, you are running `bundle exec rails g model Somthing`.  Or whatever command you were running.

also what does `bundle list` say? can you see all the rails gems from the list that this command gives you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    rails (= 3.1.0) ruby depends on
  railties (3.1.0)
```

so therefor it will not bundle unless you have the source wich supplies the needed dependencies.

I suggest installing rails 3.2.3 and using that.

```
gem install rails   #will install the newest rails
```

in gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
```

then run

```
$:.bundle update.
```